# Cannot Update buildtool version from build.gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I was trying to update build tool version from build.gradle and got this Gradle Sync Error message
:- I juset went to build.gradle file inside the app directory and changed the:
buildToolsVersion '20.0.1' to buildToolsVersion '23.0.0' and then everything went wrong.

[image]

**so I looked at the SDK manager but the build tool is installed there**

[image]

What should I do now?

Comment: yes I am Using Android Studio

Comment: what do you mean by "can you add all the build.gradle files in your project" Sorry did't get it

Answer (score 1):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.didyoufeelit"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

try to update this into the build.gradle